# Increase security of sign up form code

Tags: php, sql, security, mysqli

Does my PHP look secure enough for a sign up form?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","db_name");
$sql="INSERT INTO users values (?, ?, ?)";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql)) {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", 
    $_POST["username"], $_POST["pwd"], $_POST["email"]);
  if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "User added!";
  }
}
```

Comment: From PHP side of view: you might want to check if connection is successful first. It's important to check if all variables are valid (not empty, matching something). Also someone might spoof form and pass an array instead a string. From security point of view: missing salting and hashing of the password. You might also want to make sure that mail and username are unique (but you can do that using sql unique keys).

Comment: It depends on your php version and available plugins. PHP 5.5 - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php . Earlier versions http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php - I recommend blowfish algorithm. Take a look on second comment, it shows a quite secure way to generate salt.

Comment: @Misiur 2nd to top or 2nd to bottom?

Comment: On crypt function page, comment by "steve at tobtu dot com"

Comment: @Misiur Just that one line of code?

Comment: @Misiur: Why don't you turn your comments into an answer? There is enough there to be a code review.

Comment: it looks ok, but I would like to see how you are handeling the input. Are you sanatizing all inputs and salt/hashing?

Comment: @SaggingRufus Yeah, I'm salting and hashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a good and solid `Insert`, probably pretty safe, but this still allows a user to enter data into the database that could be run at a later time,  you should still check the input coming in before inserting it into the Database even though it has been "prepared".

The prepare just means that the insert will not break anything, but if you run a SQL Query on the information in that column where someone has entered SQL injection Characters it could still crash the database.

Please make sure the input is safe all the way around.  Alert the user that they cannot enter certain characters but be aware you are asking for an e-mail address there too. The Password should be encrypted, not sure whether you should do that here or in the Database itself, probably in the PHP, but that is another review altogether.